# one to many dimensional relation ssas

Tags: sql-server, ssas, business-intelligence, msbi, ssas-2012

Need your help or suggestions over my case here in SSAS modeling

I am basically struggling with 4 tables, **Customer, CustomerPhone, CustomerEmail, CustomerBusinesses.**
Providing the sample data below, only the dimension Customer is linked to all, because Customer has one values.
The other tables will have a scenarios like a customer can have multiple emails, phone and can be a customer of mutiple businesses.
I cannot maintain all these into one custome dimension, because my fact is referring based on Global Customer ID, if I join the Global Customer ID's will duplicate

[image]

My reporting end is Power BI, and my intent is by selecting a Customer Name on filter and it show show me multiple phone, emails and for which all business he is been.

I tried using a reference Relationship, but it is not working, though it work, it has to queries against a measure group.
Would there be any way to achive this.

Let me know if any additional info is required here.

Thanks